# Bio and statistics question

Tags: statistics

I have a control group X, and we're doing a test X with a product A, and a test X with product B. Is there any statistical test that you would recommend doing between the 3 in order to determine if there are important differences between the 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

The test used should be determined by the data. The choice of test for matched or paired data is described in and for independent data in.

For example, for:

1. Nominal Variables, use MenNear's Test
2. Ordinal (ordered Categories) use a Wilcoxon
3. Quantitative (Discrete or Non-Normal) use a Wilcoxon
4. Quantitative Normal use Paired Tests.

This is obviously a very high level answer but based on the nature of the input variable, one would then narrow it down to $\chi^2$, Fisher's, Logistic Regression, Mann-Whitney or Kruskal-Wallis.